# How to configure the interface Cassandra listens on?

Tags: cassandra

I am trying to set up a test Cassandra 3.3 cluster on Ubuntu 15.10 with OpenJDK 1.8. The nodes can't talk to each other because Cassandra only listens on the loopback interface, as `netstat` shows.

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7199          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          :::*                    LISTEN
```

I have tried to insert my external IP address in  /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yml.

- `listen_address`: I tried the actual external IP address and leaving the field empty.
- `rpc_address`: I tried the actual external IP address and 0.0.0.0.

I also tried modifying the following in /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh.

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<actual external IP address>"
```

Between each change I stop the service, delete /var/lib/cassandra/data/system, and restart the service.

How does one configure the interface Cassandra listens to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rpc_address` is the address that external app clients will use to connect with Cassandra.

`listen_address` is the address that Cassandra will use to connect to other Cassandra nodes.

I would make sure that your nodes can communicate on that IP.  Specifically, Cassandra will use port **7000** for inter-node communication (7001 if using node-to-node SSL).  The best way to test this is with telnet.  If it works, this is what you will see:

```
$ telnet 192.168.0.101 7000
Trying 192.168.0.101...
Connected to 192.168.0.101.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

So I would:

1. Figure out whether or not the nodes can communicate with each other on port 7000.
2. If they can, set the IPs that they see each other as in each cassandra.yaml's `listen_address`.
3. You'll probably also want to pick one of those as a seed node.

Comment: I upvoted and selected your answer because it is correct. However my issue was a typo in a filename (/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yml instead of yaml). Your answer provided the confidence that my config was correct and that I should look elsewhere. Also, I must stop working late.

Comment: Aaron - I am trying to run `cassandra` on google cloud and want to use external IP. I specified the external address in `rpc_address` but got error when trying to start `cassandra`- `INFO  [main] 2019-12-17 19:00:37,251 Server.java:159 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 (unencrypted)...
Exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException) encountered during startup: Failed to bind port 9042 on xx.xx.x.xx.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on x.x.x.x.x.` Woudl you know what might be the issue?